# bash script 'here strings'

Tags: c, bash

I am going to be running a C program from inside a bash script.

The c program expects inputs from the user.  total number of inputs are 7. which are on 7 different lines. for example

```
Please enter input1: 
1
Please enter input2: 
2
Please enter input3:
3
```

so on..
I did some reading up and found out that bash here strings are used for this purpose.  So I ran the program, from inside a bash script with the following command

```
./runnable <<< 1
```

this solves the purpose when the input is required only once...what is the solution when multiple inputs will be required?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally the answer might be probably "it depends", but if the program is something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  char s1[100], s2[100];
  printf("Enter string1:");
  fflush(stdout);
  fgets(s1, sizeof(s1), stdin);
  printf("Enter string2:");
  fflush(stdout);
  fgets(s2, sizeof(s2), stdin);
  printf("string1: '%s', string2: '%s'\n", s1, s2);
  exit(1);
}
```

Then you can feed it input using the "document here" syntax:

```
$ ./a.out <<_END_ 
> string1
> string2
> _END_
Enter string1:Enter string2:string1: 'string1
', string2: 'string2
'
```

This syntax is something that has become more than just shell - it's also a handy construct in Perl and Ruby.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of it depends on exactly how your program is parsing it's input.  Many C programs can and will parse space-delimited integers without difficulty, so something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
./runnable <<< "1 2 3"
```

would be the easiest solution.  If the program does require a carriage return after each number, then:

```
#!/bin/bash
./runnable <<< "1
2
3"
```

could do the trick.  Please note the quotes around the input strings of both example -- they make the difference between "working" and "not working", although for the life of me I can't recall exactly why it's necessary for the first one.